# Page postback webpage flickers

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have 15 dropdowns on the page, and they are cascading dropdowns.
second dropdown loads data depending on the first one.

Whenever i change the dropdown item. It is posted back, and page flickers
can i remove it
so that my page stays still when the next dropdown loads

Comment: Use update panel...Look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers and keep your drop-down-lists in update panel. Page will not filckker

Answer (score 1):

You want to do one of two things:  either avoid the postback altogether, or set it up so that the whole page doesn't refresh.  There are a few approaches I can think of to fix this problem:

1) Take a look at the [CascadingDropDown control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) in the asp.net AJAX toolkit

2) Look into using the UpdatePanel control to cause the part of the page with cascading content to post back asynchronously

3) If the content of the cascading dropdowns is static, you may want to implement the dropdowns in a client-side script; either using native JavaScript events or a JavaScript framework like jQuery.  [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vemuhemanth/cascading-dropdown-in-Asp-Net-using-jquery/)

Comment: Is it not possible without using Ajax?

Comment: @user1546173 It depends on whether you need to pull the conditional data from the server.  If it's data that won't change (for example, pick a month and then the day in the month), you can do it using client-side script alone.  Otherwise it's either AJAX or a postback.